# How to add std=c++11 flag to clang-cl?

Tags: windows, c++11, clang, compiler-flags

I tried to compile a C++11 program with clang-cl under Windows. Clang-cl is the wrapper around clang to be more compatible with cl (Visual Studio compiler). I tried to add `-std=c++11` and `/std=c++11` and both get rejected. This is to no surprise as cl has no C++11 flag.
But I can not use C++11 features with clang-cl.

How can I enable C++11 support in clang-cl?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the documentation mentioned before says: http://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html#clang-cl

> clang defaults to C++11 for Windows targets.

Maybe you don't need to pass any flag to clang-cl.

Comment: I try to compile a code base that was developed and compiled with Linux and Clang 3.5. I tried it with CMake and Visual Studion 2013 and Clang 3.5 as the tool chain. The compiler error out because of either shared_ptr or nullptr. I'll double check whether it is really C++11. Because the configure checks for _has_attribute(deprecated) failed on Windows, too.

Comment: @usr1234567 C++11 works for me by default with clang-cl. Make sure you run it from within an environment configured to locate the Visual Studio headers and such. That is, the vcvarsall.bat script which sets up the cmd.exe environment so you can use cl.exe is also needed by clang-cl.

Comment: @bames53 I think I did. It is inside the build directory of my CMake project. Or do I have to set this explicitly with CMake?

Comment: @usr1234567 If you're running clang-cl from cmd.exe you need to configure the environment yourself, or use one of the Visual Studio cmd.exe shortcuts. If you're building from within a Visual Studio project then it should be set up for you by VS.

Comment: I tried with a cmd from Visual Studio where everything is set. It works, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

For any future visitors, using `/std:c++17` for clang-cl works for me. Notice that there is no equals sign after std.

Answer (score 3):

From the [official docs](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html#clang-cl):

```
/std:<standard>
```