# clang-cl on Windows 8.1 compiling error

Tags: c++, windows, compilation, 64-bit, clang

I just started using clang-cl 3.7 on Windows.
I tried to compile my code on my WIN8.1 machine through Visual studio 2015, and trough command line. Needless to say that before that, in the same cmd, I ran `vsvarsall` with the `amd64` option.

Here is my code:

```
#define UNICODE
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>

 int main() {

 int a = 0;
 if(0)
__asm _emit 0xE8
else
a=3;

if (IsDebuggerPresent())
MessageBox(
    NULL,
    (LPCWSTR)L"Debugger detected!!",
    (LPCWSTR)L"!!!!!",
    MB_ICONWARNING | MB_CANCELTRYCONTINUE | MB_DEFBUTTON2
    );
 return 0;
 }
```

Here is what I put in the command line:

```
C:\Program Files\LLVM\bin>"C:\Program Files\LLVM\bin\clang-cl.exe"     "C:\Users\Dav
 id\Source\Repos\DY Obfuscator 2015-20162\DY Obfuscator\Source.cpp"
```

Compiling in VS2015 worked ok, but I cant compile on the command line because I get this error:

```
C:\Program Files\LLVM\bin>"C:\Program Files\LLVM\bin\clang-cl.exe"    C:\test\Sourc
e.cpp
In file included from C:\test\Source.cpp:3:
In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio  14.0\VC\INC
LUDE\iostream:6:
In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INC
LUDE\istream:6:
In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INC
LUDE\ostream:6:
In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio   14.0\VC\INC
LUDE\ios:6:
In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INC
LUDE\xlocnum:7:
In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio   14.0\VC\INC
LUDE\cmath:656:
In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INC
LUDE\xtgmath.h:8:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio     14.0\VC\INCLUDE\xtr1common(207,22
) :  error:
  use of undeclared identifier 'char16_t'
    struct _Is_integral<char16_t>
                        ^
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio   14.0\VC\INCLUDE\xtr1common(213,22
) :  error:
  use of undeclared identifier 'char32_t'
    struct _Is_integral<char32_t>
                        ^
In file included from C:\test\Source.cpp:3:
In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INC
LUDE\iostream:6:
In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INC
LUDE\istream:6:
In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INC
LUDE\ostream:6:
In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INC
 LUDE\ios:6:
In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio    14.0\VC\INC
 LUDE\xlocnum:10:
 In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INC
LUDE\streambuf:6:
In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INC
LUDE\xiosbase:6:
In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INC
LUDE\xlocale:8:
In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INC
LUDE\stdexcept:6:
In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INC
LUDE\exception:7:
 In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INC
 LUDE\type_traits:6:
 C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio   14.0\VC\INCLUDE\xstddef(405,14) :
  error:
  use of undeclared identifier 'char16_t'
    struct hash<char16_t>
                ^
 C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE\xstddef(411,14) :
   error:
  use of undeclared identifier 'char32_t'
    struct hash<char32_t>
                ^
 In file included from C:\test\Source.cpp:3:
 In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INC
 LUDE\iostream:6:
 In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INC
 LUDE\istream:6:
 In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INC
  LUDE\ostream:6:
 In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INC
 LUDE\ios:6:
 In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INC
 LUDE\xlocnum:10:
In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INC
 LUDE\streambuf:6:
In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INC
 LUDE\xiosbase:6:
In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INC
 LUDE\xlocale:8:
In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INC
 LUDE\stdexcept:7:
In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio  14.0\VC\INC
LUDE\xstring:6:
 In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INC
 LUDE\xmemory0:8:
 C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE\limits(611,33) :
  error:
  use of undeclared identifier 'char16_t'
 template<> class numeric_limits<char16_t>
                            ^
 C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE\limits(901,33) :
  error:
  use of undeclared identifier 'char32_t'
 template<> class numeric_limits<char32_t>
                            ^
 In file included from C:\test\Source.cpp:3:
In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INC
  LUDE\iostream:6:
 In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INC
 LUDE\istream:6:
 In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INC
 LUDE\ostream:6:
 In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INC
 LUDE\ios:6:
 In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INC
 LUDE\xlocnum:10:
 In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INC
 LUDE\streambuf:6:
 In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INC
 LUDE\xiosbase:6:
 In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INC
 LUDE\xlocale:8:
 In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INC
 LUDE\stdexcept:7:
 In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INC
 LUDE\xstring:6:
 In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INC
 LUDE\xmemory0:10:
 In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INC
 LUDE\xutility:8:
 In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INC
 LUDE\utility:7:
 C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE\iosfwd(267,21) :
  error:
  use of undeclared identifier 'char16_t'
    struct char_traits<char16_t>
                       ^
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE\iosfwd(276,21) :
   error:
   use of undeclared identifier 'char32_t'
    struct char_traits<char32_t>
                       ^
 In file included from C:\test\Source.cpp:3:
 In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INC
 LUDE\iostream:6:
 In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INC
  LUDE\istream:6:
 In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INC
  LUDE\ostream:6:
  In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INC
 LUDE\ios:6:
  In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INC
LUDE\xlocnum:10:
 In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INC
 LUDE\streambuf:6:
 In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INC
 LUDE\xiosbase:6:
 In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INC
 LUDE\xlocale:8:
 In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INC
 LUDE\stdexcept:7:
 C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE\xstring(2623,22)
  :  error:
  use of undeclared identifier 'char16_t'
 typedef basic_string<char16_t, char_traits<char16_t>, allocator<char16_t> >
                 ^
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE\xstring(2623,53)
  :  error:
  expected unqualified-id
 typedef basic_string<char16_t, char_traits<char16_t>, allocator<char16_t> >
                                                ^
 C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE\xstring(2625,22)
 :  error:
  use of undeclared identifier 'char32_t'
typedef basic_string<char32_t, char_traits<char32_t>, allocator<char32_t> >
                 ^
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE\xstring(2625,53)
 :  error:
  expected unqualified-id
 typedef basic_string<char32_t, char_traits<char32_t>, allocator<char32_t> >
                                                ^
In file included from C:\test\Source.cpp:3:
In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INC
LUDE\iostream:6:
In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INC
 LUDE\istream:6:
 In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INC
 LUDE\ostream:6:
  In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INC
 LUDE\ios:6:
  In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INC
 LUDE\xlocnum:10:
 In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INC
 LUDE\streambuf:6:
 In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INC
 LUDE\xiosbase:6:
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE\xlocale(1004,30)
  :  error:
  use of undeclared identifier 'char16_t'
    class _CRTIMP2_PURE codecvt<char16_t, char, _Mbstatet>
                                ^
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE\xlocale(1328,30)
 :  error:
  use of undeclared identifier 'char32_t'
    class _CRTIMP2_PURE codecvt<char32_t, char, _Mbstatet>
                                ^
 14 errors generated.
```

Comment: `char16_t` and `char32_t` are an addition of C++11, did you compile with the relevant flags?

Comment: what flags? I don't think so...

Comment: my bad http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25992401/how-to-add-std-c11-flag-to-clang-cl (clang defaults to C++11 on Windows).

Comment: I added `-Xclang -std=c++11` and `-Xclang -std=c++14` to the command, but that didn't help! :(

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I finally found that I need to add the following to the command line:

```
-fms-compatibility-version=19.00
```

In a reply to [Clang bug report #24231](https://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=24231), Reid Klecker explained why this is necessary:

> "In [Visual Studio] 2015, `char16_t` became a builtin type. Previously, it could not be builtin because 2013 defines it in their headers. By default, Clang tries to be compatible with 2013. To target 2015, pass [`-fms-compatibility-version=19`] to `clang-cl`. The argument can be the whole version number that `cl /?` spits out."

So my final command is (including general libs):

```
clang-cl.exe "C:\test\Source.cpp" -fms-compatibility-version=19.00 ^
   -Fe"C:\test\Source.exe" "kernel32.lib" "user32.lib" "gdi32.lib" "winspool.lib" ^
   "comdlg32.lib" "advapi32.lib" "shell32.lib" "ole32.lib" "oleaut32.lib" "uuid.lib" ^
   "odbc32.lib" "odbccp32.lib"
```

Comment: It seems that since this reply, they added means of automatically setting `-fms-compatibility-version` based on your environment variables (actually by checking `cl.exe` version number). So, make sure you have `cl.exe` visible to clang, and this option will be set automatically.

Comment: @thelink2012 Is that supposed to be in Clang 4.0? Using the prebuilt binaries on Windows 10 with MSVC 2017 (cl.exe 19.10), the compatibility setting still defaults to 18.

Comment: @DavidBrown I found this behaviour on Clang 3.9.1, not sure if they changed it on 4.0.